# Spring Data Elasticsearch documents not being deserialized

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

Spring Data Elasticsearch version: 3.2.6.RELEASE
Elasticsearch version: 7.6.2

I am attempting to deserialize a list of `MerchantCategory` using:

```
SearchQuery getAllQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
        .withQuery(matchAllQuery())
        .build();
return elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(getAllQuery, MerchantCategory.class);
```

The String id field is correctly set on the list of `MerchsntCategory` but the other fields remain `null`.

I have confirmed that the documents fields are persisted in Elasticsearch using Kibana.

The field mappings are submitted to Elasticsearch when the Spring Boot application is started:

```
request [PUT http://127.0.0.1:9200/merchantcategory/_mapping/merchantcategory?master_timeout=30s&include_type_name=true&timeout=30s] returned 1 warnings: [299 Elasticsearch-7.6.2-ef48eb35cf30adf4db14086e8aabd07ef6fb113f "[types removal] Using include_type_name in put mapping requests is deprecated. The parameter will be removed in the next major version."]
```

Here is the `MerchantCategory` class:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@Document(indexName = "merchantcategory", type = "merchantcategory")
public class MerchantCategory implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("ParentId")
    private Long parentId;

    @SerializedName("Name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("Description")
    private String description;

    @SerializedName("UrlName")
    private String urlName;

    @SerializedName("Id")
    private Long categoryId;

    @SerializedName("MerchantsInCategory")
    private List<MerchantCategoryRelationship> merchants;
}
```

I use `gson` to serialize:

```
val bulkRequest = new BulkRequest();
entities.subList(startIndex, endIndex).forEach(e ->{
    String source = gson.toJson(e);
    val indexRequest = new IndexRequest(index).source(source, XContentType.JSON).type(type);
        bulkRequest.add(indexRequest);
});

highLevelClient.bulkAsync(bulkRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT, getListener());
```

I have also tried the same thing with `merchantCategoryElasticsearchRepository.findAll();` and have the same issue.

Why is it that the only field that is serialized is the String id field and not the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use Jackson as serializer?

Than you have to use: `@JsonProperty`

```
@JsonProperty("UrlName")
private String urlName;
```

If you are using GSON as serializer you have to use `@SerializedName`.

```
@SerializedName("UrlName")
private String urlName;
```

Comment: What is the difference between `@JsonProperty` and `@SerializedName`?

Comment: JsonProperty is part of Jackson, SerializedName is part of Gson

Comment: If I understand correctly, the issue I had was that I was using the Gson annotation `@SerializedName` initially. But Spring Data Elasticsearch uses Jackson for deserialization and so doesn't recognise that annotation. So switching to `@JsonProperty` allowed the fields to be identified and mapped correctly.